# How to make "Choose Destination Directory" dialog appear after "Create Test" in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, unit-testing, kotlin

I am studying unit-testing from Google codelab.

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-testing-basics#5

There is one step to choose the folder in AndroidTest/Test destination dialog
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk7TF.png)

But my Android Studio doesn't show this dialog so I need to drag my file into test package everytime.

How to set the Android Studio to let this dialog open?

Answer (score -1):

1. Update gradle & android gradle plugins
2. Update all dependencies plugins ( I prefer to delete gradle variables and use dependencies with direct version number to avoid conflict )
   like this

> implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.1"

3. Update kotolin version
4. update target sdk to 33
5. Add exported = "true" to the MainActivity tag in the manifest

   ```
     <activity
       android:name="com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.todoapp.tasks.TasksActivity"
       android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
       android:exported="true"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme.OverlapSystemBar">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```

Comment: Issue remains for me after these steps.

Answer (score -1):

1- Open file > project structure

- update Android gradle plugin version to **4.2.2**
- update gradle version to **6.7.1**

2- When you create a test and the dialog appears to you then
edit the destination package to the root package of the project
for example, you will find the default package like this
**com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.todoapp.statistics**
remove **.statistics**
make your destination package like this
**com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.todoapp**

Comment: Issue remains for me after these steps.